# Wicket multiple listViews

Tags: listview, wicket

I have a list of values and i would sort them by there domain and display them, and on loading i don't know exactly the list's items so i can't make it static. So can we create, dynamically a listView of listView or is there any component which do a particular hierarchic like this:

*List1:

- ELEM1
- ELEM2
- ELEM3

*List2:

- ELEM1
- ELEM2
- ELEM3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents a ListView from containing more ListViews in its items.

As a side-note: Judging from your other questions during the last few days, maybe it's a good idea to start with some literature like [Wicket in Action](http://www.amazon.de/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http://www.amazon.com/Wicket-Action-Martijn-Dashorst/dp/1932394982?ie=UTF8&qid=1311858451&sr=8-1&site-redirect=de&tag=brainshare-21&linkCode=ur2&camp=1638&creative=6742) or the [examples](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/) at the wicket homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.
For example, your HTML may have the following structure:

```
<table>
  <tr wicket:id="outerList">
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr wicket:id="innerList">
          <td>....</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your Java code would follow the same structure, but I'll leave that as an excercise for you to learn something.